# Get count of each OPTIONAL MATCH

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Trying to run the following query:

```
MATCH(u:User) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (u)-[:USER_TYPE]->(adminType:UserType {type:'Admin'}) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (u)-[:USER_TYPE]->(userType:UserType {type:'User'}) 
RETURN DISTINCT { adminCount: count(adminType), userCount: count(userType) }
```

This returns me the count of the admins, but the users are 0. If I switch the OPTIONAL MATCH and set the user first, then I get a count for the user, but not the admin. How do I get of both?

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to calculate?

Comment: I thought my cypher was pretty easy to understand. Just trying to get the count of each user type.

Comment: It did not look like that was what you are trying to do, since you are including the `User` nodes in your query. To get the counts of each type, you just need to do something like the following (without involving `User` nodes at all): `MATCH (adminType:UserType {type:'Admin'})
WITH count(*) AS adminCount
MATCH (userType:UserType {type:'User'})
RETURN {adminCount: adminCount, userCount: COUNT(*)}`

Comment: I see where the confusion was.Thanks for sharing your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `OPTIONAL MATCH` try this:

```
MATCH (u:User)-[:USER_TYPE]->(adminType:UserType {type:'Admin'})
WITH count(*) AS adminCount
MATCH (u:User)-[:USER_TYPE]->(userType:UserType {type:'User'})
WITH count(*) AS userCount, adminCount
RETURN {adminCount: adminCount, userCount: userCount}
```

Match on each pattern then count the number of matches using a `WITH` clause to bring through only the count.

**Edit**

As pointed out by @cybersam the above query takes into account the number of relationships, to get the count of `UserType` nodes with type property values of "Admin" and "User" (without taking relationships into account):

```
MATCH (adminType:UserType {type:'Admin'}) WITH count(adminType) AS adminCount
MATCH (userType:UserType {type:'User'}) WITH adminCount, count(userType)
RETURN {adminCount: adminCount, userCount: userCount}
```

Comment: Note: this calculates the number of times that the `Admin` and `User` types were related to `User` nodes. The questioner, in a comment, indicates that he/she was just trying to "get the count of each user type".

Comment: thanks @cybersam - I hadn't realized that. Answer updated.